# Ruby/Watir: go to next button of the same class

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a table where all the button are like this:

```
<button class="button_class btn" type="button">
```

I want to click in all of them using Watir/Ruby. This is the code to click on the first one:

```
browser.button(:class => 'button_class btn').click
```

What can I do to go to the next one and click on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to just click the second button (rather than clicking each and every button), you can use the :index locator.

```
browser.button(:class => 'button_class btn', :index => 1).click
```

Note:

- The :index is the position of the elements matched - ie :index 1 is the second button that has the class 'button_class btn'.
- The :index is 0-based - ie 0 is the first matching element, 1 is the second matching element, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [**`buttons`**](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#buttons-instance_method) instead of [**`button`**](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#button-instance_method) as below :-

```
browser.buttons(:class => 'button_class btn').each do |b|
  b.click
end
```